# Javascript libraries for SPA

Tags: javascript, html, single-page-application

I am thinking of creating Single Page Application (SPA) and was wondering if there is something like jQuery for extending Javascript and make it work everywhere in the same way, JayData for OData support & LINQ queries in Javascript....
Something dedicated for SPA, but I am not aware of. Any suggestions?

Comment: A truly nice LINQ in JavaScript isn't possible due to language limitations, but you can get close with libraries like underscore/lodash, and you can also get even closer if you switch to something like CoffeeScript.

Comment: Have you had a look at Breeze? (www.breezejs.com)

Comment: I am going to use TypeScript and I took a look at breeze, but as far as I researched linq-in-js libs JayData is the winner.
I do believe I am going to use this quadruple: JayData, AngularJS, jQuery (maybe) and TypeScript for all of them

Answer (score 3):

**Anatomy of a traditional webserver**

*Server-side:*

- **/** -> maps routes to controllers
- Controller -> combines Model + View to build a response
- View -> handles dynamic templating
- Model -> defines the data structures and methods used to fetch data

*Client-side:*

- Browser makes requests

*Example GET request:*

Browser requests a resource **->** server routes the request to a controller **->** controller fetches data from the model **->** controller uses the view to generate html **->** controller sends response to browser **->** browser reloads and renders the DOM

**Anatomy of a Single Page Application**

*Server-side:*

- **/** -> redirects requests back to the browser as /#!/*
- **/api/** Controller + Model - routes an API requests and builds a response from the model

*Client-side:*

- **/#!/** -> maps routes to controllers
- Controller -> combines Model + View and updates the DOM
- View -> handles dynamic templating
- Model -> fetches data from the API via AJAX

*Example GET request:*

User requests resource in browser **->** client routes request to controller **->** controller fetches data from model **->** controller uses view to generate html **->** controller updates DOM

---

**There's a few key distinctions that make an SPA:**

- the majority of the processing gets offloaded to the client
- only one page (ie index.html) gets loaded by the browser
- hash fragment `/#!/*` (aka hashbang) URLs prevent the page from refreshing
- the app stays loaded until the user leaves the page
- additional resources are fetched dynamically via AJAX

*Note: Technically a SPA router isn't necessary but it makes navigating between pages a lot easier.*

**The good:**

- SPAs reduce load on the server-side allowing greater scalability
- eliminating refreshes makes for a nicer less jerky user experience
- front-end developers can build the whole ui in the browser
- the back-end team doesn't have to deal with ui/templating
- with data decoupled as an independent API, data can be used on multiple platforms (ex mobile app)

**The bad:**

- increase load on the browser/DOM
- some search engines+ may have issues indexing
- don't work in browsers when Javascript is disabled

*+Webcrawlers have been improved recently to support Javascript so they can index SPA. In the past you'd have to generate static copies of the pages and serve them to the crawler from the server-side.*

---

**Now, to answer your questions:**

> jQuery for extending Javascript and make it work everywhere in the same way

jQuery **can** be used to load everything dynamically but I wouldn't suggest it. You also have to be careful about managing events and updates to the DOM. Why build a house out of clay when you can build it out of bricks?

> JayData for OData support

OData is nothing but REST with statically-typed responses. Javascript is a dynamic language so -- even if it supported OData - there would be no benefit in using it. If you use TypeScript it **does** support it's own flavor of JayData but you'll also need a transpiler to convert Typescript to ES5.

> LINQ queries in Javascript

There *is* a [LINQ](http://hugoware.net/Projects/jlinq) library available for Javascript. If you're talking about LINQ-to-Objects and not LINQ-to-SQL.

> Something dedicated for SPA, but I am not aware of. Any suggestions?

Yes, the newest version of the React framework leverages the new VirtualDOM to prevent DOM/layout thrashing, introduces a new HTML-like syntax called JSX to make building dynamic components a lot easier. Pushes most of the SPA to a background worker, freeing up the UI. React includes a lightweight router and AJAX support via Flux.

The Angular2 framework also leverages the latest browser features in a very similar manner but uses ES6/ES7 syntax (ie classes and decorators) to make defining components much cleaner/easier. Angular also includes a very powerful router and AJAX support + Rx (Reactive Extensions). The problem with Angular2 is, it's still in early alpha development so no-go for use in production.

Both frameworks are transitioning over to a reusable component-service model as opposed to a model-view-controller model used in older frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you should look for the book 'Single Page Web Applications: JavaScript end-to-end'.

When I learnt Javascript in the first place,
I found achieving SPA concept without any modern framework is a very tough thing.
But after buying and learning this book thoroughly, I simply use three major library(includes:TaffyDB,gevent,uriAnchor of course jQuery) to finish my first three jquery-based SPA in my first job.

These authors of the book mainly guides you how to modularize your every javascript code in a feature-based fashion.
This feature-based concept is very helpful for our SPA team,
since in the paste, our team spent a lot of time discussing how to avoid conflicting our variables in the same page,
but when modularization, we simply use jqeuryMap.find("class selector") to narrow down the scope of module, and if ncessary, use gevent to pass the necessary object to the other module in the same page.

So, if you want to use lightweight and easy-learning jquery library in your team, refer to this book~

[Single Page Web Applications](http://www.manning.com/mikowski/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Kendo UI. It's an opensource javascript library, with a MVVM framework and routing system for Single Page Applications. Plus, it's all integrated with a component-driven ui, with a lot of very useful components.

[Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/spa/index.html)

Comment: As I said in comments, I'm sticking with TypeScript as a preprocessor, AngularJS as a MV*framework and JayData for OData CRUD. So far, everything is going very well and I really enjoy Angular's approach with scopes, controllers, services and directives. I'll let you know when we go live to see how it's been going.

Answer (score 0):

For LINQ Queries Check this library

https://github.com/iabdelkareem/LINQ-To-JavaScript